# How to add a new line in Gtk textview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, newline, gtk3

Here is my problem, I can't quite find the answer elsewhere. I want to show some text in a Gtk textview (python3), with a new line after each piece of text. When I use "\n", it shows "\n" rather than actually adding in a new line. Is there a way that I can fix this?

This should be a reproducible version of my problem and then my output... (ps. I'm not an experienced programmer)

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

records = ()
tv = Gtk.TextView()

records += ("a", "\n", "b", "\n", "c", "\n")
tb = tv.get_buffer()
tb.set_text(str(records))

sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
sw.set_size_request(300,400)
sw.add(tv)

w = Gtk.Window()
w.add(sw)
w.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

current output in Gtk window:

```
('a','\n','b', '\n', 'c')
```

desired output in Gtk window:

```
 'a'
 'b'
 'c'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been shown a way to solve this problem by using `%s` string formatting. Here is a sample of the code I was actually working with:

```
tv = Gtk.TextView()
    for record in records:
        records_str += "Title: %s \nAuthors: %s \nSource: %s\n\n" %(record.get("TI"), ", ".join(record.get("AU")), record.get("SO"))

    tb = tv.get_buffer()
    tb.set_text("".join(records_str))
```

This prints "Title", "Author" and "Source" on separate lines.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the `textbuffer`, without reading it first, can be accomplished using `iters` (which sort-of point to the buffer's contents). For example, you can add at the buffer's end [asking for an `iter` at the end](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/TextBuffer.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.get_end_iter):

```
    bff = Gtk.TextBuffer()
    view = Gtk.TextView(buffer = bff)
    bff.set_text("This is the beginning\n")

    iter = bff.get_end_iter()
    bff.insert(iter, "And this is a newly inserted line\n")
```

You can also insert:

- at the beginning ([`get_start_iter`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TextBuffer.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.get_start_iter)),
- at a certain offset (in characters) into the text ([`get_iter_at_offset`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TextBuffer.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.get_iter_at_offset)),
- at a certain line ([`get_iter_at_line`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/TextBuffer.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.get_iter_at_line)),
- at certain 'marks' you leave in the text ([`get_iter_at_mark`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TextBuffer.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.get_iter_at_mark)), etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the data in your variable named `records` in one string like this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

records = ()
tv = Gtk.TextView()

records += ("a", "\n", "b", "\n", "c", "\n")
tb = tv.get_buffer()
# join in one single string
tb.set_text("".join(records))


sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
sw.set_size_request(300,400)
sw.add(tv)

w = Gtk.Window()
# Don't forget to connect your window's close button 
# to Gtk.main_quit signal, or whatever the signal you want
w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
w.add(sw)
w.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Output within Gtk window will be:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Thanks, this did partially work, but not totally as my actual code turned out to be a little more complex!

Comment: You can edit your question and update how complex your code is and i'll update my answer in order to help you. You're welcome